# mongodb bind to 0.0.0.0 in windows 10

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am trying to bind 0.0.0.0 for my mongodb
I am doing "**C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0**"

but getting error:

```
2018-07-26T18:08:17.909+0530 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2018-07-26T18:08:18.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=14516 port=27017 dbpath=C:\data\db\ 64-bit host=xhdpranayd30
2018-07-26T18:08:18.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] targetMinOS: Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2
2018-07-26T18:08:18.271+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.0
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 3b07af3d4f471ae89e8186d33bbb1d5259597d51
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: 2008plus-ssl
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-07-26T18:08:18.272+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0" } }
2018-07-26T18:08:18.273+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating
2018-07-26T18:08:18.273+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-07-26T18:08:18.273+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

How to solve this??
I don't have permission to reinstall mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the log output, you can see clearly that the issue isn't the network address, but that the data directory is not found, look for `Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating`. Create that directory (or set another existing location with the `--dbpath` argument) and MongoDB should start.

Comment: @pranaydas - Would you mind then accepting my answer, as it solved your issue?

Comment: Yes it is solved my issue, I tried to upvote your answer, but somehow I am blocked to do any voting for some unknown reason :(

Comment: Along with upvoting, you can al so "accept" an answer, by clicking the green check mark. That is the best action to take when someone has completely solved your issue. Upvoting means something a little different.